# random number generator is generating huge negative numbers

Tags: java, random

So I am creating a random code that's not necessarily pertinent to anything at this level, but I'm more testing a few ideas. So for some reason my code will work randomly, but for most of the time it's throwing out a random negative number usually in the vicinity of -413796084. I don't know why it's doing this and I am trying to keep the numbers in the vicinity of 0 - 50. I thought I had done it right but obviously I haven't. Also I am relatively new at Java, if that helps explain any mistakes I made.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
class damagecalc {
public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random randamage = new Random();
    int totaldmg;

System.out.println("Will you (a) attack, (s) defend, (d) skip your turn, (f)         magic,     (i) use an item?");

    String dmgString = input.next();

    char dmgChar = dmgString.charAt(0);


    if(dmgChar == 'a'){
        for(int finaldmg=50;finaldmg<=50;finaldmg++){
        totaldmg = randamage.nextInt(10);
            }
    totaldmg = randamage.nextInt();
    if(totaldmg >= 50){
        System.out.println("You have defeated the monster!");
    }else{
        System.out.println("Damage Dealt:" + totaldmg);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT------------------------------------------------

So I changed my code and fixed some things and now it's just spitting out 0 every time. Maybe now it will be a little easier to figure out. But I definitely need help.

This is the new code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
class damagecalc {
public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random randamage = new Random();
    int totaldmg;

    System.out.println("Will you (a) attack, (s) defend, (d) skip your turn, (f) magic, (i) use an item?");

    String dmgString = input.next();

    char dmgChar = dmgString.charAt(0);


    if(dmgChar == 'a'){
        for(int finaldmg=1;finaldmg<=50;finaldmg++){
            }
        totaldmg = randamage.nextInt(1);
        if(totaldmg >= 50){
            System.out.println("You have defeated the monster!");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Damage Dealt:" + totaldmg);
           }
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Show us the code, please.

Comment: it's spitting out 0 because you have randamage.nextInt(1) with the 1 being non-inclusive.  You're telling it to generate a random number between 0 and 0.

Comment: you need to not have any of these: totaldmg = randamage.nextInt();  if you look at the code before you changed it, you have totaldmg = randamage.nextInt(10) and then you follow it up immediately with totaldmg = randamage.nextInt();  this would overwrite your correct number with the extremely large +/- numbers

Answer (score 1):

```
totaldmg = randamage.nextInt();
```

Random.nextInt() can return **any** legal value for an int, including the massive negative ones, which isn't likely to be the result you want here. Give `nextInt` some integer as an argument to constrain it to the desired range.

also, I'd take a look at this loop because chances are that it doesn't do what you think it does.

```
for(int finaldmg=50;finaldmg<=50;finaldmg++){
    totaldmg = randamage.nextInt(10);
}
```

The body of the loop executes only once and `totaldmg` is overwritten right after the loop anyway.

EDIT: if you want just to generate a number between 0 and 50, you can just replace this:

```
for(int finaldmg=50;finaldmg<=50;finaldmg++){
    totaldmg = randamage.nextInt(10);
}
totaldmg = randamage.nextInt();
```

with this:

```
totaldmg = randamage.nextInt(51);
```

In case you're wondering about that `51`, that is the excluded upper bound - meaning that you'll get damage amounts that are at least zero and at most 50.

Comment: That's weird because I have another random num generator that works, and it's the exact same, but for some reason this isn't cutting it. Do you know what I would replace it with?

Comment: No, I can't tell how you want your program to work. All I know is that you had a problem with the RNG giving you negative integers - well, that's something to be expected when using Random.nextInt without passing an argument like you do earlier.

Comment: You're fine. I'm just confused and don't really know where to go from here. Thank you for your answer though. It'll help point me in the right direction.

Comment: Actually I think you might just want to remove the problematic random call altogether. You already assigned a value to totaldmg in the loop right before it - although the loop has problems of its own.

Comment: I think you're right. What I'm basically doing is making a battle system that will literally just take the input (being 'a' in this case) and causing it to randomly generate a number between 0 and 50 and based on that number it prints a message. So I did that For Loop to give the limit for the randamage to run until it hit a total of 50. But you're right, I'm not even sure if that's right. ha ha.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying - I'll modify my answer to reflect that spec.

Comment: So I tried that earlier and I tried your suggestion again, but it still spits out huge negative numbers. I wonder if it has something to do with my Scanner input to char conversion.

Comment: That is very, very odd. I would understand if randamage.nextInt() did that (notice the lack of arguments there!) but if I understood correctly you no longer had any calls like that - only randamage.nextInt(51) that should stay neatly bounded. Are you sure you're testing an up-to-date version of the program (freshly compiled instead of some earlier version)?

Comment: I Googled a little bit and found this: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=8481 although it's stated as resolved. But point is it could be a bug if there really isn't some other problem.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry my first answer was c#, changed.

What you want is

```
totaldmg = randamage.nextInt(50);
```

use 51 if you want it to generate between 0 and 50 since it is exclusive.

Or if you're going for 50+random damage between 0 and 10, use this:

```
totaldmg = 50 + randamage.nextInt(10);
```

The other answer pointed out that weird for loop and I really don't know what you're going for anymore

---

Lol based on your discussion below the other answer, and assuming you don't find the real answer to your problem, if the negative numbers are between 0 and -50 then just use

```
totaldmg = Math.abs(randamage.NextInt(50));
```

and if the numbers are still negative and HUGELY negative:

```
totaldmg = Math.abs(randomage.NextInt(50)) % 50;
```

Awful, awful fix, but if it's honestly a bug or something this would be about as good in theory

Comment: With both options it still is spitting out the negative numbers. :(

Comment: are they huge negative numbers still or within 50ish?

Comment: They're still like -993631793. This is driving me crazy. ha ha.

Comment: I edited my answer, try my suggestion at the bottom.  I felt dirty even writing that solution but it should work.

Comment: I'm sorry I made you soil your hands. However it's still coming up largely negative on both fixes.

Comment: try Math.floor(Math.random()*51);

Comment: you were overwriting your answer with the second totaldmg = randamage.nextInt(); after you called the function correctly.  all you need is totaldmg = randamage.nextInt(10); ONCE lol

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out. One I'm an idiot for having my totaldmg = randamage.nextInt(); twice, but when I took out one of them I was only getting 0's. So when I changed it to totaldmg = randamage.nextInt(50) it worked perfectly. Sweet. Thanks everyone for working with me. You all are fantastic individuals.